# Conectar a una VPN usando Cisco AnyConnect

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy empezando a programar con Python y no encuentro info muy clara del código que debería utilizar para llamar y/o conectar a una VPN utilizando Cisco AnyConnect.

Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda.

Saludos,

Comment: Hola Edwin, esta pregunta es muy amplia, debes editarla para añadir más detalles sobre lo que quieres hacer, lo que hayas investigado/desarrollado hasta el momento y los problemas o dificultades que te estés encontrando. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.